# Objective-C Category Return AppDelegate as property

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I'm creating an Objective-C category on the UIViewController class. In my project, I want one singular and easy way to get the app delegate.

Here's what I'm doing

```
// header file UIViewController+AppDelgate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ExampleAppDelegate;

@interface UIViewController (AppDelegate)
@property (weak, nonatomic, readonly) ExampleAppDelegate *appDelegate;
@end

// implementation file UIViewController+AppDelegate.m
#import "UIViewController+AppDelegate.h"
#import "ExampleAppDelegate.h"

@implementation UIViewController (AppDelegate)

- (ExampleAppDelegate *) appDelegate {
    return (ExampleAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

@end
```

Should I define the property as weak? I think it would be bad to retain this guy as it would normally have retains on view controllers referenced within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

weak/strong in this case is a moot point, since there is no local instance variable holding a pointer. ARC will do the right thing (i.e. it will not send more retains than releases for any given scope).

Comment: In the case of when not using ARC, can I still use weak. Or does this not really made?

Comment: I'm not sure they matter without ARC either, since you are not defining an actual instance variable, just declaring that there will exist a "getter" at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a Utility class with a class method that does the same thing, then you can reference it something like:

```
[Utility appDelegate];
```

and you wont have to add a property to every single ViewController that needs to access the AppDelegate, the way you currently have it setup.

Comment: The category may be more efficient, since it adds a method to an existing class, instead of adding another class. It's not so much "adding a property to every single" as it is "making this little chunk of code handy to any instance"

Comment: I really like the idea of just being able to get reference to it in any view controller. This way I don't have to do '(ExampleAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]' all over the place.

Comment: @developerdoug I can see how it would be simple to add a category for you, but if you wanted to use your code in a different class, like a logic class or a subclassed UINavigationBar, etc you would have to reference it the long way unless you either create another category, or just use a utility class like I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your implementation you dont need to define a property, you only need to declare the method `-(ExampleAppDelegate *)appDelegate;`

This of course would only work if called on an instance of the class unless you made it a class method.

Comment: Very true, but I'd rather have a property.